# android animation disappearing with custom icons

Tags: java, android, animation, button, toolbar

I have a little problem. I'm using some actions like add, add people and so on in my toolbar. The problem is that when I set them a custom icon, the ripple-like animation disappears. How do I get it back? I really like the way it looks and it also gives instant visual feedback so the user knows for a fact that it's been pressed.

Comment: use https://github.com/traex/RippleEffect

Comment: thanks, but the effect it makes is not really appealing to me. Perhaps there's a way to revert the animations to their original state like every default button has?

Comment: i know it's very nitpicky, but i'd be grateful if you could suggest something else :)